# Angular project working tools

Tags: windows, node.js, angularjs, installation, directory

I am working in an AngularJs project in one computer with Windows 7. What I would like is to be able to continue working at home and in any other computer.

If I have installed inside a folder called C:/Client-side 
- My Nodejs and all modules Nodejs needed
- My AngularJs project

Whould it work in both computers just replicating the project from one to the other?
Thank you

Comment: why not ? test and see...

Comment: I will this night and will came back and confirm it. Just was wondering if I could need something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copying the code from one computer to the other will work. However you can go for an online repository management system such as Github or BitBucket. BitBucket is free so you can go for that to have private repos in it.

For Nodejs you can also have a package.json built so that in your other system you can just deploy the code folders and then do 'npm install' to fetch dependencies (node modules)

More on [package.json](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/npm/what-is-the-file-package-json)